# How come it says array is undefined?

Tags: javascript

Here is a javascript sample:

```
var obj =
{
   options:  [],

   init:  function( )
   {
       options['one'] = 'one';
       for( k in options )
       {
          alert( options[k] );
       }
   }
};
```

instead of prompting "one", it says undefined, why?

Comment: be careful when using a 'for x in obj' loop, if you run that code you will see a whole heap of interesting functions being alerted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to reference it as `obj.options`.

Aside from that, you should use an object `{}` instead of an array `[]` if you're not going to be using numeric indexes.

```
var obj =
{
   options:  {},

   init:  function( )
   {
       obj.options['one'] = 'one';
       for( k in obj.options )
       {
          alert( obj.options[k] );
       }
   }
};
```

*If* you call the `init()` function from the `obj` reference, then you could use `this` inside the `init` function instead of `obj`.

```
var obj =
{
   options:  {},

   init:  function( )
   {
       this.options['one'] = 'one';
       for( k in this.options )
       {
          alert( this.options[k] );
       }
   }
};

obj.init();  // Makes `this` refer to `obj` in the `init` function
```

---

As [@CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms) noted, you should declare your variables with `var`.  In your `for` loop, `k` is no declared with `var`, and as such will become a global variable.

Comment: @dave: Using `this` would depend on how the `init` function is called. If you're doing `obj.init()`, then yes, you could use `this.options` inside the `init` function.

Comment: @david: Not always. See above.

Comment: +1 for more complete answer than mine, and the `[] => {}` that I missed. Deleting my answer shortly.

Comment: If you use it correctly, then 'this' is perfectly safe to use, and is far more adaptable because you're not hardcoding the name of the object into its implementation.

Comment: @david: I didn't say it wasn't safe. It just can't be assumed.

Comment: Off-topic but in addition, I would recommend to use the `var` statement to declare the `k` variable on the `for-in` loop: `for(var k ...` otherwise `k` will become a property of the global object (`window.k`).

Comment: @patrick, but you're assuming the object will always be called obj, what if later he does something like `someArray.push(obj); obj=something else;`?

Comment: wow, these are all good learning tips, thanks a bunch.  I clearly need to go back and learn javascript objects again.

Comment: @david: We don't know the ultimate use of the code. I'm not making *any* assumptions. As I said above *"It just can't be assumed."* Along the same line, what if later he passes that function as a callback? `someOtherFunc( obj.init )` When `someOtherFunc` calls the callback it won't be called from the context of `obj` unless that function happened to have a reference to it and knew to use it. Or if it gets assigned to a variable? `var func = obj.init; func()` Again it is not called from the context of `obj`.

Comment: Woah, ease up, all I'm saying is that we are both making assumptions. I just find it more likely that the object will be renamed, and less likely that he will pass function pointers around.

Comment: @david: You may be absolutely right, especially with a name like `init`. Not enough info in the question to know for sure. I'd tend to lean toward `this` as well if for no other reason than the fact that it is a direct reference to the object without a scope chain traversal.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing looks very similar, in form and concept, to something called the 'Module pattern' in javascript.
It is a very powerful tool, and if you want to learn I highly recommend you read up on it.

Here is your code, rewritten as a module, with changes to avoid polluting the global scope, and to fix a potential problem with your `for in` loop. 
It also defines `options` as an object, rather than an array, as you seem to be using it as a hashtable rather than with numeric indices.

```
var module = (function() {
    //here options is private
    var options = {};

    var init = function() {
        options['one'] = 'one';
        for (var k in options) {
            if(options.hasOwnProperty(k)){
                alert(options[k]);
            }
        }
    };

    //These are the things that are public
    return {
        init:init
    };
}());


module.init();

alert(module.options); //undefined (because it's private)
```